# How to create a logical vector that indicates whether the values in two columns are the same across categorical factors in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying my best to articulate this, so here goes.

I have a table of gene information. However, I am going to be using a generic example for the sake of this question.

```
> test_dt <- data.table(c("b", "a", "a", "b"), c(1, 4, 1, 5), c(4, 6, 4, 8))
> colnames(test_dt) <- c("category", "start", "end")
> test_dt
   category start end
1:        b     1   4
2:        a     4   6
3:        a     1   4
4:        b     5   8
```

I want to append an additional column to this table that indicates whether `start` and `end` are the same across different `category` values (in my case as well as in this example, I am only dealing with two categories):

```
   category start end in_both
1:        b     1   4    TRUE
2:        a     4   6   FALSE
3:        a     1   4    TRUE
4:        b     5   8   FALSE
```

I know this seems painfully basic but there are holes in my R knowledge that periodically need to be filled and paved over. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Tip: When working with `data.table` instead of `colnames()<-` you can (and should) use `setnames()`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur thanks for the heads up, I didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
test_dt[, in_both := uniqueN(category) == 2, by = c("start", "end")]

   category start end in_both
1:        b     1   4    TRUE
2:        a     4   6   FALSE
3:        a     1   4    TRUE
4:        b     5   8   FALSE
```

Comment: This was great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `all` and `%in%`

```
test_dt[, in_both := all(c('b', 'a') %in% category), .(start, end)]
test_dt
#   category start end in_both
#1:        b     1   4    TRUE
#2:        a     4   6   FALSE
#3:        a     1   4    TRUE
#4:        b     5   8   FALSE
```